# Change Attr External Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a webchat [here](https://www.busyatwork.com.au/chat-sample/) and am trying to add a placeholder attr without any luck. There is a chat script someone has added. I have tried using .live handler without luck. Help appreciated

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

 var chat = new jQuery.webChat({
        queue: 'BAWWEBCHAT'
    });
    var original = chat.localize;
    chat.localize = function (key) {
        switch (key) {
            case "MAN_HDR": return "Chat with us";
            default: return original.apply(chat, arguments)
        }
    }

 jQuery("#wc-email").attr("placeholder", "Your Email");

    jQuery("body").on("click", function(event) {
        chat.hideChatbox();
    });

    jQuery("body").on("click", ".wc-webchat", function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });



});
```

Comment: Are you sure you have an element with id 'wc-email'? Please show your html, this gives us a better chance of answering.

Comment: Yes there is an ID.  I managed to get it to work by using an event that I located with the chat documentation https://www.busyatwork.com.au/chat-sample/: 

trigger:  function() {
              jQuery('#wc-email').attr('placeholder', 'Your Email');
            }
But it would really useful to know how to modify an attr of an element once the external script has rendered.